# PHP: Find if booked dates are within any of the specified date range

Tags: php

I have solved my client's initial requirement when he originally asked me to assign special rate if a customer booked within a specified date range.

However, he has extended the requirement to multiple date ranges now and I'm left dumbfounded on how to manipulate the working code I had previously.

Here's the code I used previously for 1 date range

```
$book_start_date = $start->format('d F Y');
$book_end_date = $end->format('d F Y');

$daterange_season = array('2017-01-20', '2017-02-15'); 
/* 20 January 2017 - 15 February 2017 : Peak Season */

$daterange_booked = array($book_start_date, $book_end_date);

$range_min = new DateTime(min($daterange_season));
$range_max = new DateTime(max($daterange_season));

$start_book = new DateTime(min($daterange_booked));
$end_book = new DateTime(max($daterange_booked));

if ( $start_book >= $range_min && $end_book <= $range_max ) { 

// Apply special rate

}
```

Now I have multiple date ranges

```
2016-11-25 -----> 2017-01-02
2017-01-20 -----> 2017-02-06
2017-03-17 -----> 2017-03-27
2017-04-27 -----> 2017-05-04
2017-05-25 -----> 2017-05-31
```

Can anyone show me the direction to take?

FYI, I'm a CSS person actually but sometimes required to do jQuery and PHP.

Comment: What is wrong with the code that you currently have ? It looks logically correct.

Comment: I need to list more season/date ranges not just 1 season as per original code. And I have no idea how to pair start date and end dates of each range

Comment: You should use multidimensional array for ranges definition and than loop over it and check all ranges if any contain correct date for apply special rate

Comment: Thanks @diaraf for the direction. I'll try to google this now!

Comment: I think once you switch the logic to the multi-dimensional array, you might also be able to get rid of the `min` and `max` functions. This will make your code simpler.

Comment: Thanks @Maximus2012 for the tip. Hopefully my brain will be able to compute this haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for You with any ranges You want.

```
$book_start_date = $start->format('d F Y');
$book_end_date = $end->format('d F Y');

$daterange_season = array(
     array('2017-01-20', '2017-01-25'),
     array('2017-01-29', '2017-02-15')
); 

$daterange_booked = array($book_start_date, $book_end_date);

$start_book = new DateTime(min($daterange_booked));
$end_book = new DateTime(max($daterange_booked));

foreach($daterange_season as $singleRange){

    $range_min = new DateTime(min($singleRange));
    $range_max = new DateTime(max($singleRange));

    if ( $start_book >= $range_min && $end_book <= $range_max ) { 

    // Apply special rate
        break;
    }

}
```

Comment: Wow thanks @diaraf I was just reading http://webcheatsheet.com/php/multidimensional_arrays.php trying to grasp the idea of multidimensional array and you posted a code! To be honest, I learn better from studying people's codes. I will do a bit more reading and will try your code out. Thanks so much!

Comment: Since there are pairs, instead of `min` and `max` use `$daterange_booked[0]` and `[1]` and `$singleRange[0]` and `[1]`.

Comment: @AbraCadaver You're right but I use the code provided by Iwani and just modify it

Comment: Thanks @diaraf for your code. It works like a charm and insyaAllah I believe I am able to do a similar task from now onward. Yay!